# What is causing this strcpy segfault?

Tags: c, malloc, strcpy

Here is my code and it faults here `strcpy(pSrcString,"muppet");` Well infact it does whenever I use strcpy.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{

char *pSrcString = NULL;
char *pDstString = NULL;

/* muppet == 6, so +1 for '\0' */
if ((pSrcString = malloc(7) == NULL))
{
    printf("pSrcString malloc error\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

if ((pDstString = malloc(7) == NULL))
{
    printf("pDstString malloc error\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

strcpy(pSrcString,"muppet");

strcpy(pDstString,pSrcString);

printf("pSrcString= %s\n",pSrcString);
printf("pDstString = %s\n",pDstString);
free(pSrcString);
free(pDstString);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have misplaced your parentheses in `(pSrcString = malloc(7) == NULL)`. In that way, you are first checking the result of `malloc(7)` against `NULL` (which turns out to be false or `0`), and then assigns that to `pSrcString`. Basically:

```
pSrcString = 0;
```

Well of course that is not going to give you a valid memory to let `strcpy` write things to. Try this instead:

```
(pSrcString = malloc(7)) == NULL
```

Likewise for `pDstString`.

Aside, if you just want to have a copy of the string, you can use the [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) function. That allocates memory for you and takes care of calculating the length itself:

```
pSrcString = strdup("muppet");
```